# Interprating API response from Google server

Tags: iphone, driving-directions

I am developing a Location based application. application will show route between to locations with turn by turn directions(as in native "Maps" application with all the nodes).  I am requesting to google maps for directions in following way.(as example directions between cupertino and stanford)

```
NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?dirflg=d&output=dragdir&saddr=Stanford&daddr=cupertino"];
    NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSString* apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"apiResponse=%@", apiResponse);
```

At the console I got response

`{tooltipHtml:" (12.9\x26#160;mi / 19 mins)",polylines:[{id:"route0",points:"kklcFzishVdBb@??@s@rB{PHi@Xk@??bEmDrDgF~DeHVcAhCgG??rFfEv@RbFHnEa@vBGnEd@\\P~EjGtMxK??zNwTxB_ChCqD??bAt@bDdBvDt@~BXrC@xBS|NiClA@fAPvBdA~@dAlI`Q`AxAr@n@|@d@rFxA|AlA`AnAz@t@l@`@nAd@zQnC??bA\\^XVr@Az@KVa@\\m@B[UWq@?i@zBaI`@oBd@mDt@kS~@kG`AoDrA_DhAqB~AkBlCuBlDiB~Cw@lU}CbBa@~B{@jE_CvAgAjDyDhQ{SvFuFpUgSzD{EdAcB`BiDlA_DfAaEbIk`@r@mERyBZkMXkHX{DjA{GtBaG|CcFxC{CfAy@vUaMjDmEvA}BxCkG`AwCfAyEtCiRv@{ClB_F|B_EpDkEvAoAdGcE|FwEbBmBvBmDhAiCtMma@dAcCrBmD`LiNlB{CfAcCtEaMtKsU`CmEdP{WbB_EbAoDr@}Dd@aFLkCC_FK_C{C}YMqGPsGRyC\eCdAeFpCaLdBiJXcENgHa@qIcIwo@[*DWeFKk[Dyc@??\gHbAgI?*@??|bAG???s@_@?",levels:"BBB???BB????BB?@???@??BB??BB???@????@????@??????@BB?????@???@????@???@??????@??????@???@????@?@?????@?????@??????@??@??@?????A???@????@??????@???@?BB??BBBB?B",numLevel`s:4,zoomFactor:16}]}

I am not able understand above response. Does this response contains turn by turn directions? If not how can get these directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google Directions API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/):

> overview_polyline contains an object holding an array of ***encoded***
>   points

That means you cannot directly read real points value.

Also:

> Note: the Directions API may only be used in conjunction with
>   displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without
>   displaying a map for which directions data was requested is
>   prohibited.